# open multiple files in tabs from command line

Tags: files, tabbar

Emacs-27.1 ships with a new tab-bar-mode minor mode. This puts a tab bar at the top of each Emacs frame. Each tab in the tab bar can display multiple windows.

Is there any way to invoke Emacs from the command line and have it open multiple files in separate tabs?

For instance, I want to run a command like the following:

```
$ emacs --some-flag file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Emacs should open `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt` in separate tabs (instead of separate buffers).  Is there some way to get this to work?

---

Vim has a `-p` flag that allows it to open files into separate tabs instead of just separate buffers.

Answer (score 3):

Having just read on the Emacs Stack Exchange [Make `display-buffer` open buffer in new tab](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61677/make-display-buffer-open-buffer-in-new-tab) and applying it to your situation, I suggest you put in your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq display-buffer-base-action '(display-buffer-in-tab))
```

save it and then call from the command line *without any additional flag*:

```
$ emacs --some-flag file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: Oh, that's a smart idea.  However, I don't actually want to use Emacs with `display-buffer-base-action` turned on all the time.  Is there some way to set it to only be active while processing the files from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Based on halloleo's answer:

```bash
emacs --eval "(setq display-buffer-base-action '(display-buffer-in-tab))" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

This is probably not something to remember, so maybe you want to have a shell-alias for it:

```bash
alias emacstabs='emacs --eval "(setq display-buffer-base-action \'(display-buffer-in-tab))"'
```